# How can 'the nested renamer error' be solved from this jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to replicate the next [notebook](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/notebooks/blob/master/Seismic_acquisition.ipynb) for a class, specifically the line Input [32]

```
In[32] bin_stats = joined.groupby('bins_index')['offset'].agg({'fold': len, 'min_offset': np.min})
```

but I get the error `SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported`

Comment: Use `bin_stats = joined.groupby('bins_index').agg({'fold': len, 'min_offset': np.min})`

Comment: I did what you say and now it says `Column(s) ['fold', 'min_offset'] do not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
bin_stats = (joined.groupby('bins_index')
                   .agg(fold = ('offset', len), 
                        min_offset = ('offset', np.min)))
```